# Upload file to Google Drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, google-drive-api

I need to upload files on my google drive (pdf, word, excel), how can I do it in ASP.NET using C#? Could you explain me step by step all the passages? If it can be useful I put my last test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ASPSnippets.GoogleAPI;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

...

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GoogleConnect.ClientId = "my_client_id";
        GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = "my_client_secret";
        GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0];
        GoogleConnect.API = EnumAPI.Drive;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
        {
            string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            string json = GoogleConnect.PostFile(code, (HttpPostedFile)Session["File"], Session["Description"].ToString());
            GoogleDriveFile file = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<GoogleDriveFile>(json);
            tblFileDetails.Visible = true;
            lblTitle.Text = file.Title;
            lblId.Text = file.Id;
            imgIcon.ImageUrl = file.IconLink;
            lblCreatedDate.Text = file.CreatedDate.ToString();
            lnkDownload.NavigateUrl = file.WebContentLink;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.ThumbnailLink))
            {
                rowThumbnail.Visible = true;
                imgThumbnail.ImageUrl = file.ThumbnailLink;
            }
        }
        if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Access denied.')", true);
        }
    }

    protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["File"] = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        Session["Description"] = txtDescription.Text;
        GoogleConnect.Authorize("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");
    }
}


public class GoogleDriveFile
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string OriginalFilename { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnailLink { get; set; }
    public string IconLink { get; set; }
    public string WebContentLink { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

But I have this error:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:61360/Prova.aspx,
>   does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/831126948299-2bopcsp3aee3harncqp5dpkq77sii3he.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=831126948299
>   to update the authorized redirect URIs.

Request Details:

> ```
> scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
> redirect_uri=http://localhost:61360/Prova.aspx
> response_type=code
> client_id=831126948299-2bopcsp3aee3harncqp5dpkq77sii3he.apps.googleusercontent.com
> approval_prompt=auto
> access_type=offline
> ```

I've insert the redirect page but it gave me the same error.

Comment: When you register with an OAuth site, you tell it what web page to redirect the user to, once the app has been authorised.  The error message says ``http://localhost:61360/Prova.aspx`` is not the one you have registered.  What is the URL you have registered with google apps?

Comment: I do not insert any redirect page... I only created an application and used the id and the secret in my program. What should I put as redirect url?

Comment: Maybe I can explain better: in "console.developers.google.com", in "credentials", in the "ID client OAuth 2.0" I have created I have put only the name field. While in the "consensus product screen" I have only my email address and the name of the product

Comment: the link in the error message (the "Visit ... to update the authorized redirect URLs") is your friend

Answer (score 0):

The redirect uri you add in Google developer console must exactly match what you are sending from  in your case you are sending http://localhost:61360 so should add http://localhost:61360 in your redirect URI.   Or possibly http://localhost:61360/AuthCallback

Tip: Make sure you have visual studio set to not add random port numbers.